# Representative observations from the hierarchical clustering results

Tags: clustering, matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using the hierarchical clustering to generate groups from unlabeled dataset (or observations). I’m using the matlab function `Z_SAMPLES = linkage(id,'average','@distcustomfun');` with my custom function `distcustomfun`.

I’m interested in finding the observation the most representative of each cluster? Any idea how can I find this observation.

Comment: Any sane idea will do. You may define a representative observation as, for example, the medoid of a cluster. You should be aware, however, that you have used linkage method `average` which itself is not tied with an idea of medoid, centroid or other "representative" or "central" place inside the cluster. So, your representative observation will be not related to the optimization function done by the clustering.

Comment: @ttnphns I was thinking to calculate the distance between the observations in each cluster, and pike the observation that has minimum distance. What do you think?

Comment: You are probably thinking of the medoid. Search/Read about it on this site and the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchical clustering will usually *not* compute a *representative* object? Because that costs time and is not needed for the algorithm. Even "centroid" linkage does not compute the position of the centroid.

Thus. don't look for such a function - it does not exist.

If you want a representative object. roll your own logic.

For example, the object with the least average or least squared average distance to all others of the same cluster, or the arithmetic mean (if you have coordinates) could be of interest.